# Export Excel file (.xls) from large json response

Tags: json, excel, blob

I have a json response ~10,000+ records, i want them to export json response into excel document (.xls), with some formatting.

Application is designed in C# .NET, i am displaying json data in jqGrid.

Any link or support how this can be achieved is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [NPOL](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) Its free and support XLS and XLSX both.

You can go through this [blog](http://www.leniel.net/2009/07/creating-excel-spreadsheets-xls-xlsx-c.html#sthash.utl63Qix.dpbs) for reference